# How to make WhatsApp for iOS fetch image for preview set in og tag in my website?

Tags: ios, wordpress, facebook-opengraph, yoast

I am trying to set og:image tag for my website so that users can see the thumbnail image when the website link is shared. Now the thumbnail is working fine facebook, twitter and Linkedin. But when I share the link on WhatsApp it only works for android. In the case of WhatsApp for ios, it tries to load the image but fails and only website description is sent with the website link.

I have already followed all the answers available on this forum.The image I am trying to use for thumbnail is `669 × 378 px` and is 89KB in size. There are no errors according to the facebook debugger. My website is in WordPress, so I was using Yoast SEO earlier but to solve this problem I tried by adding meta tags manually as well, but nothing works for WhatsApp for IOS.

These are the metatags found by facebook debugger for my website https://www.indiadappfest.com

```
These are the raw tags that we found
Meta Tag    <meta property="og:locale" content="en_US" />
Meta Tag    <meta property="og:type" content="website" />
Meta Tag    <meta property="og:title" content="India Dapp Fest 2019 | Asia&#039;s top-notch revelation on blockchain based applications" />
Meta Tag    <meta property="og:description" content="India Dapp Fest is a top-notch conference focussed on blockchain, enabling conscious decentralization and inturn, ushering in a change to pave the path for future work assemblies" />
Meta Tag    <meta property="og:url" content="https://www.indiadappfest.com" />
Meta Tag    <meta property="og:site_name" content="India Dapp Fest 2019" />
Meta Tag    <meta property="og:image" content="https://www.indiadappfest.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/03/thumbnail-2-low-resolution.jpg" />
Meta Tag    <meta property="og:image:secure_url" content="https://www.indiadappfest.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/03/thumbnail-2-low-resolution.jpg" />
Meta Tag    <meta property="og:updated_time" content="1553416119" />
```

Someone, please help me to fix it for ios.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the open graph [documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/best-practices#images) you should use 1:1 i.e square images, apart from that remove the yoast seo plugin and add the meta tags manually (i used a plugin called scripts and styles). This helped me solve the problem for the thumbnail in WhatsApp for ios. You might also want to add another meta tag with a rectangular image as Facebook will skew the 1:1 image when you'll share it on Facebook.